# How do I accurately select half of a symmetrical mesh?

Tags: mesh, selection-tools, mirror

I have this mesh that is probably nearly 100% symmetrical on both sides. I want to easily select half of the mesh, in order to hide it to have easy access to its inside. My object is directly aligned with the origin, so would there be like a Hot-key to be able to select any parts of a mesh in one side of the axis?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can select everything relative to the last selected (active) vertex.

- Select the middle vertex
- Access the menu: *Select -> Side of Active*.
  (Which has options regarding which side/axis).

Answer (score 3):

In wireframe view enable Ortho view (<kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>)

Unselect everything ( <kbd>A</kbd>)

Use **Border Select** (<kbd>B</kbd>) to draw a box around the vertices you want to select.

[image]

Hide the vertices by pressing <kbd>H</kbd>.

Remember to press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to un-hide when you are done!

Comment: While this is great for low-poly meshes, I have a really dense mesh which doesn't make selection as 100% accurate or clean as I would like.